# Is it possible to rename local group with Tableau Server Client library in Python in Tableau?

Tags: python, tableau-api

We've 100+ local group and would like to change the name of these groups. Is it possible to achieve this using tableau server client library in python?

I have written following code but it is not updating the group name in Tableau.

```
`with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
    # get the groups on the server
    all_groups, pagination_item = server.groups.get()

    # print the names of the first 100 groups
    for group in all_groups:
        old_name = group.name
        new_name = old_name.replace("RemoveThis ", "")
        group.rename = new_name`
```

Answer (score 1):

That's renaming it in memory, but you need to send those changes back to Tablaeu. To do this, use the group `update` method.

Your code would become:

```
with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
    # get the groups on the server
    all_groups, pagination_item = server.groups.get()

    # print the names of the first 100 groups
    for group in all_groups:
        old_name = group.name
        new_name = old_name.replace("RemoveThis ", "")
        group.rename = new_name

        # new line, returns the updated group
        server.groups.update(group)
```

More information in the Tablaeu developer documentation: https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/api-ref#groups